# TCL : Concatenate a variable and a string

Tags: tcl

Assume we have a variable 'a' set to 12345 :

```
set a 12345
```

Now how do i set a new variable 'b' which contains the value of 'a' and another string say 9876

workaround is something like

```
set a "12345"
set u "9876"

set b $a$u
```

but i dont want to specify `$u` instead i want the direct string to used..

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You can do:

```
set b ${a}9876
```

or, assuming `b` is either set to the empty string or not defined:

```
append b $a 9876
```

The call to `append` is more efficient when `$a` is long (see [`append` doc](http://wiki.tcl.tk/1031)).

Comment: Hey Trey, good answer. Is it better to use double quotes in these cases, or does it make no odds? E.g. `set b "${a}9876"`

Comment: @Brian: Tcl doesn't care, but you might want to do that if it makes for prettier formatting.

Comment: you would only require grouping of some sort if you were trying to concat something with a space in it, depending on whether you also need variable substitution {} or "" would be needed

Comment: There is also the `join` command, but this is intended mainly for strings with strings--as far as I understand it.

Comment: @Raj To use the `join` command you'd need to make a list, something like `set b [join [list $a "9876"] ""]`

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, @TreyJackson. I was missing that information.

Answer (score 7):

other option is to use set command.
since
set a 
gives value of a we can use it to set value of b like below

set b [set a]9876

Answer (score 4):

Or，you can use `format`

`set b [format %s%s $a $u]`

Answer (score 3):

From Tcl 8.6***.2*** onwards, there is `string cat` which can be used to solve this problem.

```
set b [string cat $a 9876]
```

Answer (score 1):

Other option is to use concat command like below.

set b [concat $a\9876]

Answer (score 0):

I don't get what you mean the direct string... I'm not sure if you want...
However, if you want the value of 12349876 you can do:

```
% set b [concat $a$u]
12349876
```

If you want $a or $u to be part of the string, just add a backslash '\' before the desired variable.